# Keep editor label and input on the same line

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using MVC 3 `@html.EditorForModel`, the auto-generated template spits out

```
<div class="editor-label">....
<div class="editor-field">....
<div class="editor-label">....
<div class="editor-field">....
```

Both classes are floated left so that the elements fit the horizontal space.

When the list of fields is about 10, the lines sometimes break between label and input; this looks bad.
What is the best way to keep them on the same line?  If I were coding manually, I could wrap them inside another div, such as

```
<div class="editor-wrap">....
    <div class="editor-label">....
    <div class="editor-field">....
```

and float "editor-wrap".  However, in keeping with not wanting to hand-code each page, is there some way to enhance/change the behaviour of EditorForModel?  Or can something be done at the .cshtml (view) level with a custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can completely customize the templates MVC uses. In your Views/Shared/EditorTemplates directory, for example, you can create a template named Foo.cshtml (or whatever view engine you are using). When you call EditorForModel you can pass the name of the template (it is a parameter on one of the overloads). I recommend this series of articles to really understand the whole process:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: Okay I read all 5 parts and am not too much wiser. Which template am I overriding? I am after the exact behaviour described in the question. If you can provide contextual help it would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not asking me to create a /Edit.cshtml for each and every model, are you?

Comment: No, you can create one file, call it CustomEdit.cshtml, in Views\Shared\EditorTemplates. Then in your main view where you call EditorForModel, you pass in "CustomEdit" as the template name (a parameter to one of the overloads). The CustomEdit.cshtml template I believe can just contain your wrapping <div> and then another call to EditorForModel (but this time, with no template name, so you can use the built-in one for the rest). There is model metadata available to you at this point hanging off of the context if you wanted to get really specific.

Comment: That still gives me one <div> wrapper for the Model, not every pair of label-edit/label-display. Have I missed something?

Comment: Oh, I see. Then what you do is override the MVC template for the data type. For a string property on the model, it comes from String.cshtml. You can start with what MVC uses by looking up the 'default template' in that blog article. Then just wrap the div around that. You'd need to do this for each data type that the model might contain.